# Issue trying to access mysql through VPC in AWS-RDS through lambda

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have setup a VPC and an RDS database using mysql through a nodejs lambda using serverless.

The issue I am having is that I get a `server internal error` when testing the lambda. The lambda is using the same VPC as the RDS.

Could this be a permission issue where the lambda needs direct permission to the db instance. If so does anyone have any suggestions on what permissions would be required.

Thankyou

Here is part of the code I am using, this is to test a query and log the result to cloudwatch. It does not show up and only shows timed out.

it seems to work locally using serverless. This is just for educational purposes.

```
    let pool  = mysql.createPool({
        host: host.length > 0 ? host : body.host,
        port: port.length > 0 ? port : body.port,
        user: body.username,
        password: body.password,
        database: body.dbname
    });

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS result', function (error, results, fields) {
            // And done with the connection.
            //connection.release();
            // Handle error after the release.
            if (error) throw error;
            else Logger.info(JSON.stringify(results));
        });
    });
      return {statusCode:200, body: JSON.stringify({})};
}
```

Comment: Have configured the security group of your Lambda to allow traffic to RDS and the security group of RDS to allow traffic from your Lambda?

Comment: I am using the same VPC for RDS and lambda, the security group ports have been defined for inbound and outbound. Mysql 3360 and http, https are both set in the same security group. it still timeouts.   Is their something missing

Comment: Can you maybe show you security groups configuration (screenshot)?